# Vectorized Implementation of Softmax Regression

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, octave, softmax

I’m implementing softmax regression in Octave. Currently I’m using a non-vectorized implementation using following cost function and derivatives.

[image]

[image]

Source: [Softmax Regression](http://ufldl.stanford.edu/wiki/index.php/Softmax_Regression)

Now I want to implement vectorized version of it in Octave. It seems like bit hard for me to write vectorized versions for these equations. Can somebody help me to implement this ?

Thanks

Upul

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is very similar to an exercise in Andrew Ng's deep learning class, they give some hints
http://ufldl.stanford.edu/wiki/index.php/Exercise:Vectorization